# Why are so few votes on Chemistry.StackExchange?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, up-votes, votes

For example most viewed [question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/444/can-an-atom-have-more-than-8-valence-electrons-if-not-why-is-8-the-limit) (viewed 26k Times) and only **36** votes? Or next [one](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/54/how-does-chloroform-degrade-nitrile-gloves) (800 times viewed) has **22** votes. I do not understand why the voting system on the Chemistry.StacExchange is not working well. Do anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recently I answered a couple of questions, did not receive any upvotes or accepts and earned the **Tenacious** badge. Life could be worse!

Moderators and frequent supporters of Q&A sites want to build vivid communities.

But these sites always attract another type of users too: the ephemeral ones that are too busy to read textbooks, too lazy to think about their assignments and - on top - claim that *"googling did not reveal anything"*. **The latter mostly is a blatant lie.**

These guys only want to get their homework fixed and don't care about accepting your answer. If you enjoy the site, mark the duplicates and don't pamper the lazy and the liars.

Don't get me wrong: Homework questions are fine. I like them and it is fun to think about basic topics that you haven't touched in years.

ManisEarth wrote:

> [...] however what this site does need is more questions and users.

I doubt it. Sheer numbers won't make it. Have a look at [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/). I get the impression that the majority of users there are *one-time-wonders*, people that refuse to think before doing something stupid on their systems. And being lazy, they don't bother to read manpages, run a google search or even search on the Q&A site itself before firing their questions.

Do I sound like a grumpy old man? Probably, but this is neither the type of user, nor the type of question anybody can want here.

What can and should we do on Chemistry.SE beyond what we're doing already? **Hardly anything!**

*Is there an option to automatically add a comment to every question of to remind the the users in their option to accept an answer and, supposed they have sufficient reputation, to make use of their right to vote?*

I don't know if that would make a difference.

At the end of the day, it is our decision to spent some of our time here and think about chemistry. We can keep the site tidy and the crap level low, but otherwise:

**Enjoy yourself, relax and keep your expectations low.**

Answer (score 4):

Chemistry is a beta site, less than two years old. There aren't that many users around who can vote, and of those who can, not all are active.

We're slowly gaining traction though, it's easier to get votes than it was a year ago, and we have more activity.

Not sure how we can improve the voting, however what this site does need is more questions and users. Also, there are a lot of [unanswered](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/unanswered) questions out there that need answers.

Comment: It would be useful to attract people from ReserchGate.